# cmake: install opencv using external libjpeg library

Tags: opencv, installation, cmake, libjpeg

I have two versions of libjpeg library. One is the system library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so`, and the another is the newer one that I have built manually `/vol/me/lib/libjpeg.so`. I want to install `opencv` that uses the new library instead of the system one. How can I use cmake/cmake-gui to do that?

Comment: Take a look inside _CMakeLists.txt_ file and figure out which environment variable is used to locate libjpeg library. You can then modify that environment variable to make it point to your newer _libjpeg_ library location.

Comment: @yildirim in CMakeList.txt I only see two options: "do not build libjpeg" (which means CMake found the existing libjpeg in the system), and "Build libjpeg from source shifted with opencv"). There is no option for me to choose a specific path to libjpeg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465735/724461

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile OpenCV with libjpeg-turbo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465209/how-to-compile-opencv-with-libjpeg-turbo)

Comment: @AndreyKamaev It works. Please make it as an answer so that I can accept.